# Magento 2: Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time Change Message

Tags: magento2, checkout, messages, global-messages

I would like to change message

> "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

In which file, i can change? Can it will be manageable by Admin?

Answer (score 7):

You can change this message from CSV file.

Below is the **location** and **name** of csv file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n - **en_US.csv**

Override it in your **custom module** or **theme** and **replace your message** with **default**.

Also it is **not manageable** from **Admin**.

Comment: We have to only update 2nd column value right?

Comment: 2nd column value is used for multilangual purpose , if you have override this file in your custom theme or module then update the first column value so in future if you want to use it as multilangual then you can pass another language value in second column , hope it mean

Comment: `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\ThemeName\Magento_Checkout\i18n\en_US.csv` & i changed second value still it's not working

Comment: I tried all the way, but seems not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49272/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-manthan-dave).

Comment: Hi @Manthan. Still have issues. Can discuss on chat?

Comment: `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\i18n\en_US.csv` It's working fine if i change 2nd column value, but not working by overriding it :(

Comment: @AnkitShah put your csv file - app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv it will work. also you can put same in app/i18n/en_US.csv as well . Try both will work

Comment: Nope it's not working

Comment: @AnkitShah have you tried both method ? have you puted in app/i18n/en_US.csv  and change second column value and try ? also have you check same theme is apply on the store where you see the changes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49409/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-manthan-dave).

Comment: Hi @Manthan Still it's not working :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use csv(translation) file to change it as it can not be managed from admin

Comment: Which CSV file & location?

Comment: i recommend to create a new theme with translation file or overriding the files for this purpose
This can be done by adding translation in the core file but it is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way of changing that text.

Copy this file:
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

to your custom theme at this path:
app/design/frontend/YOUR-VENDOR-NAME/YOUR-THEME-NAME/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Change the text in line 82, which will begin with: translate=" 'Sorry....

You can change the text between the single quotation marks to whatever you would like to display on the frontend.