# Magento 2: Change Text On Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-community, localisation

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2

I would like to change `Shipping Address` to `Shipping/Billing Address`.

[image]

I have already below, but it's not working for me.

[Magento 2: Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time Change Message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147775/magento-2-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time-change-mes)

This file `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html` takes value from `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\i18n\en_US.csv`

Comment: You can set value inside csv file using theme i18n folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The easiest way is that we translate this text on our custom module or theme:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

2) We also can override the template: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`.

Comment: Hi @Khoa i already tried that things. But it's not working. Need to only deal with `en_US.csv`. I tried 4-5 ways but not working

Comment: How you translate? Please update your question.

Comment: Yes i changed in CSV file `Shipping Address, Shipping/Billing Address` but it's not working at all. Cleared cache & Also done Static Content deploy & all commands

Comment: You're clear or disable Browser Cache?

Comment: So this will be path for `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\MyTheme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\shipping.html` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Try to deploy static content again.

Comment: So no need to use `en_US.csv` can directly change in file right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. However, I think should use translation way. I still debugging.

Comment: Nope. It's not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49954/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ankit-shah).

Answer (score 7):

To Change label, You need to copy following file to your theme folder.

```
<magento root>/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Now copy this file to following.

```
 <magento root>/app/design/frontend/`<vendor>`/`<theme>`/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Please follow proper directory structure. Now Open shipping.js file and find **initialize** function near about line no **76**.

In that function you need to replace line no 88.

```
$t('Shipping') to $t('Shipping/Billing Address')
```

After replacing do not forget to regenerate static content deployment using following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hi no need to change `Shipping`, need to change below text `Shipping Address`

Comment: For that you need to update en_US.csv file or you can override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` same way as above and by copying to theme folder and update label for quick fix.

Comment: Can't do without JS? & only using `en_US.csv`?

Comment: So this will be path for `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\MyTheme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\shipping.html` ?

Comment: Yes you need to change in that file and after that redeploy content. But first delete same file from pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html

Comment: It's not working for me I tried to change like this <!-- ko i18n: $data.method_title --><!-- /ko -->