# Translate text on One Page Checkout | Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, translate

I am trying to translate on phrase on my Magento 2 One Page Checkout.

I am using a third party extension by Amasty (It should make a difference when trying to translate phrase, should it?)

What I am trying to translate:

[image]

I tried this: [Magento 2: Change Text On Checkout Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149830/magento-2-change-text-on-checkout-page)

But it don't seem to work.

I found a translation file under `/app/code/Amasty/Checkout/i18n`, however, it translates only backend phrases.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

This is the `<item></item>` form checkout_index_index file:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">                                                                            
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                                                                                
     <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">                                                                                    
          <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>                                                                                
     </item>                                                                            
  </item>                                                                        
</item>
```

UPDATE 2:

Changing the string for anything different gives me this error in the checkout:

```
quote.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
    at quote.js:32
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
    at require.js:132
    at require.js:1156
    at each (require.js:57)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
    at Module.check (require.js:917)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
```

Do I have to change anything else too?

Comment: could you open your checkout_index_index.xml file , find this text and update you question with complete xml block ? <item></item>

Comment: Take a look now. Can I change the text directly here? This would not be ideal but a quick workaround.

Comment: You can use either option, but did you changed the translation in language file and deployed static content again ?

Comment: I am in developer mode so deploying content is not necessary, although, I forced the deploy and removed the pub/static. However, this had not effect for some reason... I will change it here :)

Comment: Hymm.... I gave me error when changing it... @Naveed

Comment: strange it should not give any error, did you search this string in module also and found any record ?

Comment: I did using command line, nothing was found :/