# Magento 2.3.4 change message text 'sorry no quotes are available for this order at this time'

Tags: magento2.3, messages, magento2.3.4, change

My question is identical to this 
**[Magento 2: Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time Change Message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147775/magento-2-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time-change-mes)** 
but the answer is not correct.

I wish to change the message to something like `'please enter postcode to see rates'` I have tried extending `Magento_checkout` and amending the `magento_checkout/web/template/shipping.html` file where the message seems to be set and also the cart in `magento_checkout/web/template/cart/shipping_rates.html` but the standard message stills displays on the frontend.

anyone know how to change it?

Thanks.

Comment: your site is multi store ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this path and change the you message text

First go the this path open the `shipping.html`

> `/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

[image]

See the code and change the you want to text.

And after must be run the this commands :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And check your output :-

[image]

Helpful this answer Please accept.

Comment: Thanks I have tried this already by overriding shipping.html in (/app/design/frontend/Theme/site/Magento_Checkout/web/template) is but no joy - standard message is still displayed.

Comment: Tried this but it seems like some other extension os overriding this file and using i18n\en_US.csv file to alter message. Two extensions seem to effect same message though. Which gets priority?

Comment: Managed to resolve it was an extension overriding this file but the message was set in i18n\en_US.csv file but as I'm using en_GB I had to copy rename the file to en_GB.csv then change the message and boom.. Thanks for your suggestion above it pointed me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amasty OneStepCheckout, just change this file:

/vendor/amasty/module-one-step-checkout-core/view/frontend/web/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html

There will be this line, where you can change your desired text:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: rates().length > 0 --><div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'--><!-- /ko --></div><!-- /ko -->
```